# ID never ready for Calucated Column (SharePoint 2007 MOSS)

Tags: workflow, document-library, calculated-column, rename, unique

I have simple calcuated column that **tries** to  multiplies ID * to some number.  It worked once, but never again.  It appears ID is not ready when the calculation runs?

Is there a chance a workflow might be stopping a calculated column? Any way to force re-calculation?

So.. Say I want to produce a UNIQUE number in a calculated field, but want it to be something not easy to relate it to ID.  How would do this?

My goal is to rename a file using SPD Workflows to unique numeric string that cannot be related to anything.

Answer (score 1):

Create a list item event receiver [SPItemEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.aspx) and override the ItemAdded method. There you will always be able to grab the ID field from the properties parameter and assign it to a different field (single line of text or any other type). Attach the event receiver to your list and you are done. No workflow is required.

Comment: Do you have high level deployment steps? Would this be deployed as a WSP? Also can the event reciever be coded to delete the file, change file level permissions and redirect the user to another page?

Comment: Are we saying there is no codeless way to do this? I wonder why the limitation on being able to get ID OnCreate and do math from the BuildingString Action in SPD Workflows???? These are real weak limits IMO.

Comment: yes, deploy it as a feature inside a wsp. you can code pretty much everything you like. You could also potentially redirect the user making the event receiver synchronous (there is a property for it).

Answer (score 0):

Make the first step in your workflow a pause.  That may give time for the ID to be available?